# OpenCV/C++ - frames read from video file restart after end of the video

Tags: c++, opencv, video

I'm trying to get each frame from an mp4 video with OpenCV. I followed the standard examples but for some reason, when the last frame is read, the loop does not terminate but in fact starts again.
Here is the code:

```
while (1) {
        inputVideo.read(inputFrame);
        nFrames = inputVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES);
        cout << "Frame: " << nFrames << endl;
        n++;
    }
```

Why doesn't it stop after all the frames have been processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inputVideo.get() to detect the position of the frame in the file and use this to break out at the end